# Uniqueness of a Point in Cauchy- Cantor Lemma Zorich

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, proof-explanation, fixed-point-theorems

This a picture from *Zorich's Mathematical Analysis I*

[image]

I am having trouble understanding the uniqueness part of this theorem(last paragraph), in particular the last sentence.

**First,**

why should $c$ be unique when by the completeness axiom a second time between $a_n \le c$ we get $$a_n \le c \le b_n \implies a_n \le c' \le c \ \le b_n $$
Also I do not see uniqueness mentioned on the Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_intersection_theorem

**Second,**

I want to make sure I understand what the author is implying because it's vague to me and I also don't feel as if the last line makes a rigorous argument because it's not defined what it means to be arbitrarily small. Shouldn't a variable be 'arbitrarily small' with respect to another variable?? But going back to the argument at an earlier point, I see we can have an 'arbitrarily small' $\varepsilon >0$ such that $$a_n \le c_1 \lt c_2 \le b_n \lt \varepsilon \implies 0 \lt c_2-c_1 \lt b_n-a_n < \varepsilon$$

I can't get a contradiction even if I assume the there is an interval inside and smaller than $[a_n,b_n]$, for suppose that there is an interval $[a_k, b_k ]$ that has a length less that of $[a_n,b_n]$ then  we write $$a_n< a_k \le c_1 \lt c_2 \le b_k <b_n $$
$$\implies 0 \lt a_n -a_k \le c_1- a_k< c_2 -a_k \le b_k -a_k< b_n-a_k $$

$$\implies 0 \lt 0 \le c_1- a_k -(a_n -a_k)< c_2 -a_k -(a_n -a_k)\le b_k -a_k -(a_n -a_k)< b_n-a_k -(a_n -a_k)$$

$$\implies 0<c_1-a_n < c_2- a_n \le b_k - a_n < b_n - a_n < \varepsilon$$

but like I said this still does not lead to a contradiction in order to show that $c_1=c_2.$ Zorich has not introduced the idea of a limit point yet,if that is relevant.

Thanks in advance and if you wish to down-vote do let me know why.

Comment: This note looks familiar. What is it?

Comment: @HighGPA It's the Nested Interval Lemma in Analysis!

Comment: For this to be valid, intervals like $[a,+\infty)$ and so forth can't be considered closed. Normally, I would call intervals of the form $[a,b]$ "closed and bounded."

Comment: @user49640 I checked his notation for closed intervals is the standard [a, b] and for open intervals it is ]a, b[

Comment: This is what I understand you to mean by the first part of your question. All of the numbers $a_n$ satisfy $a_n \leq c$. Therefore, by the completeness axiom, there is a number $c'$ such that $a_n \leq c' \leq c$ for all $n$. Therefore $c$ is not unique. Is that what you mean?

Comment: The question isn't about intervals of the form $]a,b[$. It's whether you would use the word "closed" to describe an interval such as $[0,+\infty[$. I would describe that interval as closed, but evidently Zorich's book doesn't use the word "closed" in this case, or else the present theorem would not be valid.

Comment: Compactness of real number line!

Comment: @user49640 Yes! Basically this means that from $[a,b]$ we could form another interval $[a,c]$ and then why not do it again $[a,c']$?! where $c'$ possibly could be $a < c' < c$

Comment: For the second part of your question, there's actually a slight error in the text. It should say $0 < c_2 - c_1 \leq b_n - a_n$. In any case, what the author is saying is this. Let $\varepsilon = c_2 - c_1$. Then none of the intervals $[a_n,b_n]$ can have length $< \varepsilon$, contradicting the hypothesis.

Comment: Before answering your first question, Red, let me suggest that you think about this example. What if $a_n = -1/n$ and $b_n = 1/n$. Then what would $c$ have to be? And what could $c'$ then be?

Comment: @user49640 I guess $c$ could be something like $\frac{1}{2n} $ and ofcourse 0 no?

Comment: $c$ isn't allowed to depend on $n$. It has to be a single number that simultaneously satisfies $a_n \leq c$ and $c \leq b_n$ for all values of $n$. You're right about $c = 0$. Now what can $c'$ be? It has to be a number such that $-1/n \leq c' \leq 0$ for all values of $n$.

Comment: Why $c$ is not allowed to depend on $n$?

Comment: @HighGPA When you say that $c$ is in the intersection of $I_1$, $I_2$, etc., you're saying that it belongs to all of those sets simultaneously. You can't pick one number for $I_1$, another for $I_2$, and so on.

Comment: @user49640 $c$ is not allowed to depend on $n$ because of ZFC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $I_k = [a_k, b_k]$, let $|I_k| = |b_k - a_k|$

What is meant by *intervals of arbitrary small lenght* is the part of the hypothesis that states that for any $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists an interval $I_k = [a_k, b_k]$ whose lenght is smaller than $\varepsilon$. This is, $\forall \varepsilon > 0 \, \, \exists k \in \mathbb{N}: |b_k - a_k| < \varepsilon$.

Regarding the uniqueness of $c$, assume there are two distinct points $p, q \in \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} I_n$. Without lose of generality, assume $p < q$. This means that $p, q \in I_n$ for all $n$. So $\forall n: a_n \leq p < q \leq b_n$, which implies $|p - q| \leq |b_n - a_n| = |I_n|$.

But by our hypothesis, for $r = |p-q|/2$ there exists a $k$ such that $|I_k| < r$, i.e., $|I_k| < |p-q|$. A contradiction to what we found in the previous paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

If the second condition holds then there cannot exist $c_1$ and $c_2$ in $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} I_n$ with $c_1\ne c_2 .$ Otherwise there exists $k$ such that $|I_k|<|c_1-c_2|$ and $\{c_1,c_2\}\subset I_k,$ which is impossible.